# "Sending" data from vuex store to component

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to learn VueJS and Vuex and am in the process of building a task application. My components are stuctured like this:

main page

- task form
- task list
- - task list item

I add tasks through the tasks form and delete tasks through the task list item component. Both works fine! I also have an edit button next to each task list item. When I click it, the application is supposed to load the task details from the database and write it into the task form. I have successfully loaded the data into the respective task object in the store, but **I struggle to hand this data to the "local" task item in the task form component**. This component is also used for creating a task, so I am trying to find a solution to use this form again for updating.

**So overall I am trying to hand down an object from the store task object to the local component object.** Both the local object in the component and the store task component are called "task". I thought about using props, but then the adding does not seem to work, as the object is undefined at the time of adding/creating a task.

This is how I call the updating in the task list item component:

```
getTaskDetails (taskId) {
  this.$store.dispatch('getTaskDetails', taskId)
},
```

And this is what the action of loading the details in the store looks like:

```
   getTaskDetails ({ commit }, payload) {
      const task = {}
      db.collection('tasks').doc(payload).get().then(doc => {
        task.taskId = doc.id
        task.title = doc.data().title
        task.quadrant = doc.data().quadrant
        task.description = doc.data().description
        task.tags = doc.data().tags
        task.dueTimestamp = doc.data().dueDateAndTime
        task.reminderFlag = doc.data().reminderFlag
        task.urgencyFlag = doc.data().urgencyFlag
        task.importanceFlag = doc.data().importanceFlag
        // add isCompleted Flag
      }).then(() => {
        commit('GET_TASK_DETAILS', task)
        commit('SET_FORMMODE', 'update')
        commit('CHANGE_TASKFORM_VISIBILITY', true)
      }).catch(function (error) {
        commit('setError', error.message)
      })
    },
```

This is the mutation for the state.task in the store:

```
GET_TASK_DETAILS (state, payload) {
      var moment = require('moment')
      var date = new Date()
      date = this.state.task.dueTimestamp
      var s = moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
      var t = moment(date).format('HH:mm')
      state.task.dueDate = s
      state.datePicker = s
      state.task.dueTime = t
      state.timePicker = t
      state.task = payload
    },
```

Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

The root of the problem is that you are using actions to directly modify the state. If you don’t want to lose reactivity, then commit to mutations instead.

https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html
https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

This means that you don’t use **state** in an action, only get the data (asynchronously) with an action and then set the state (synchronously) with a mutation that gets the data from the action as payload.

If you follow the pattern shown in the links above, the received data should show up in your component.

There's an excellent **todo app** that you can examine - I think it's written so that one can understand a lot about VueJS (and Vuex, Vuetify, etc) just by trying to recreate what's there: https://github.com/davidgaroro/vuetify-todo-pwa

The data is passed through the **computed** property (usually), where you **return** the results of the Vuex action. (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

Comment: Thanks! I corrected that one for the get details. Bust still my question remains, how do I get the information in state.task into the local task object in the form component? Do I hand it down as a prop? If yes, how do I handle adding a task? I also added the mutation above and adjusted the code of the action

Comment: I added a reference to my answer, that really helps understand the workings of VueJS (single-file components), Vuex and a lot more. https://github.com/davidgaroro/vuetify-todo-pwa Try to recreate the files. It uses Vuetify to make the todo app enjoyable.